# Method of finding out context of webextension script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am writing a shared webextension script that should be able to execute in the background page, context script and popup page of the extension but it needs to know where it is to work correctly everywhere.

For this, the script needs a way to find out in which context (background, popup, context script) it is currently running to handle accordingly. Is there a way/JS API to get the context?

I looked into the standard webextension APIs (e.g. chrome.runtime) but I couldn't find anything related.

What I am imagining is something like:

```
const context = chrome.runtime.getCurrentContext();
if (context === "popup") {
  // Running inside popup...
} else if (context === "content") {
  // Running as a content script on a page
} else if (context === "background") {
  // Running in the background page of the extension
}
```

Comment: Usually you use completely different scripts for each, since they're basically isolated instances. They can communicate with each other of course, but it's unusual to run the same script everywhere.

Comment: There's no such API but you can check location.href. The popup and the background page have their own unique URLs and if both don't match then it's the content script.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs In my case, most of the extension code is still separate but I am writing a configuration class that will hold the configuration info. Most of the code in that class will be the same across all three (as they all need the current config), only the way of communication with other parts is different and needs to change based on the current context.